# Perform program numbers rare cousins java

Tags: java

I have the following statement and I do not understand very well what it asks for:

We say that a number n is rare when it verifies that for any number m <= n and such that both are cousins among themselves, it turns out that m is prime (two numbers are cousins each other when the greatest common divisor of both numbers is unity). 
Write a program that lists all rare numbers between 3 and a value entered by the user.
After thinking how to shed it from the statement I got the solution, which I do not know if it is the correct one. 
Can someone confirm that it is well and the result is what he really asks for?

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Cousins {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("Enter a number to calculate the cousins:");
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = teclado.nextInt();
            boolean cousins;
            for (int m = 3; m < n; m++) {
                cousins = mcd(n, m);
                if (cousins == true) {
                    System.out.println(n + " " + m + " They are cousins among themselves.");
                } else if (cousins == false) {
                    System.out.println(n + " " + m + " They are not cousins to each other.");
                }
            }
        }

        public static boolean mcd(int n, int m) {
            boolean cousins = true;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
                if (n % i == 0 && m % i == 0) { 
                    cousins = false;
                }
            }
            return cousins;
       }
  }
```

Comment: If you understood the question, can you think of how to test it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, this seems not really correct to me. It would be correct, if your excercise would be to check if the numbers from 3 to the user-entered number (lets call it n) are cousins with n. This is what you are doing in your program:
You loop over the integeres from 3 to n and check if the current number and n are cousins. By the way in the loop inside the function mcd() I would add a second condition for finishing, like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n && i <= m; i++)
```

But this is not really what you are supposed to do. You need tho check, whether the numbers from 3 to n are rare and not cousins with n.
To do so you basically need a second loop: For each number m between 3 and n you must iterate over the numbers i smaller than m to see if i and m are cousins. And for any number i, where this check returns true, see if this i is prime. If all i's that are cousins to m are prime, then m is rare.

Here is my try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cousins {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out
            .println("Enter a number to calculate the cousins:");
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = teclado.nextInt();
    boolean cousins;
    for (int m = 3; m < n; m++) {

        boolean rare = true;

        // Needless to check 1 as 1 is cousin to any number and is prime
        for(int i = 2; i <= m; i++) {

            if(mcd(i, m) && !numberIsPrime(i)) {
                rare = false;
            }
        }

        if(rare) {System.out.println(m + " is rare.");}
        else {System.out.println(m + " is not rare.");}
    }
}

public static boolean mcd(int n, int m) {
    boolean cousins = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n && i <= m; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0 && m % i == 0) { 
            cousins = false;
        }
    }
    return cousins;
}

public static boolean numberIsPrime(int n) {
    boolean prime = true;

    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if(n % i == 0) {prime = false;}
    }

    return prime;
}

}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, my description above was a bit wrong, I have corrected it now.

EDIT: Regarding your comment: The output of the program that you have written (3,4,6,8, and so on) is the perfectly correct list of rare numbers between 1 and 100 according to the definition of rare that you have given. Ok, let's look at some examples. Let's take the number 5 and check if 5 is rare. To check this we must go through all integers i from 1 to 5. If any of them is a cousin of 5, but NOT prime, then 5 is not rare . Otherwise 5 is rare (according to your definition of rare). So let's do it:

- i = 1: Is 1 a cousin of 5? Yes it is, because the only common divisor is 1. Is 1 prime? Yes. Ok. Continue with i=2.
- i = 2: Is 2 a cousin of 5? Yes it is, because the only common divisor is 1. Is 2 prime? Yes Ok. Continue.
- i = 3: Is 3 a cousin of 5? Yes it is, because the only common divisor is 1. Is 3 prime? Yes Ok. Continue.
- i = 4: Is 4 a cousin of 5? Yes it is, because the only common divisor is 1. Is 4 prime? NO!!!

So we have found a number i < 5 which is a cousin of 5 but not prime. So 5 is not rare and that's why 5 is not part of the program output.

I hope it is clearer now.